# iOS save sqlite select in NSobject

Tags: ios, sqlite, varchar, nsobject

I have a problem with sqlite. I have a select with 2 varchars on it and save it in an object. When I'm trying to get data, only one of my varchars has the string that i want. The other one is NSBlockVariable or nil.

Debugging sqlite3, it works great, and it returns perfect what I need.
This two variables are: name and store

```
product.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
product.store = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];

NSLog(@"name: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)]);
NSLog(@"store: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)]);
```

I get:

```
//name: Sunglasses
//store: RayBan
```

I have an object created like this:

```
@interface ProductsCart : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger idtrans;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger idproduct;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger idstore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *store;
```

And this is how i save it in my DAO class:

```
NSMutableArray *productList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    ProductsCart *product = [[ProductsCart alloc] init];
        product.idtrans = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
        product.idproduct = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 1);
        product.idstore = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 2);

        product.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];

        product.store = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];

        [productList addObject:product];
    }
```

In my Cart class I have a table and this is how I get the info on each row:

In viewdidload

```
self.products= [dao getProductList];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
ProductsCart * productCart=[self.products objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

int idtrans=[[[self.products objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"idtrans"] intValue];
NSString* name=[[self.products objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"name"];   
NSString* store=[[self.products objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"store"];
```

At this point:

- name is a NSMutableString and it contains "Sunglasses"
- store is a NSObject and it must be a string

I checked the stored database on simulator and the rows are perfect so the problem is not on it.

If I change the order saving the data (store in product.name and name in product.store):

```
product.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
product.store = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
```

This is what I get:

- name is a NSMutableString and it contains "RayBan"
- store is a NSObject and it must be a string

in store, sometimes I get

```
store   __NSCFString *  @"star.count.singular"  0x00007fae62068e40
```

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it saving sqlite response into a NSDictionary... I don't know why if I use a class it doesn't work